# jQuery.stop(1,1) launches next animation, but not stop(1,0)

Tags: jquery

Let's take this script:

```
$('a').hover(function() {
    $('div').stop(c,j).fadeIn();
}, function() {
    $('div').stop(c,j).fadeOut();
});
```

With `c=0,j=0`, if I over `a` several times, my div fade in and out and in and… yerk.
With `c=1,j=1`, it almost does what I want, but we got this blinking effect due to the `jumpToEnd` parameter, and it looks buggy.
So finally, what I want is `c=0,j=1`, BUT if I over in, and quickly over out and back in, animation is stopped, the next fade function won't launch and my div is half transparent. Why ?

[Another visual example.](http://jsfiddle.net/Didjo/4v8Uk/)

I meet this issue often enough, and wonder why I can't find anything on it. (Last I can remember is a comment on jQuery `stop()` page, but comments are now removed.)

Comment: http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/13370

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a better comparison between all the different usages of `.stop()`: http://jsfiddle.net/4v8Uk/13/

```
<div data-one="0" data-two="0" id="a">a</div>
<div data-one="1" data-two="0" id="b">b</div>
<div data-one="1" data-two="1" id="c">c</div>
<div data-one="0" data-two="1" id="d">d</div>
```

---

```
$("div").hover(function(){
    var d = $(this).data();
    $(this).stop(d.one,d.two).toggle("slow");
});
```

options a and b seem to be closer to what you are looking for. (0,0 and 1,0)

Update: I still don't have a clear answer as to why it happens, though I believe it happens because jQuery is seeing the element as shown already, therefore it doesn't show it. Why that doesn't effect .toggle() i don't know.

However, you can fix it by recreating your animation with .animate.

http://jsfiddle.net/4v8Uk/17/

```
$("div").hover(function(){
    var d = $(this).data();
    $(this).stop(d.one,d.two).animate({"opacity":"0", "height":"0px", "width":"0px"},"slow");
}, function(){
    var d = $(this).data();
    $(this).stop(d.one,d.two).animate({"opacity":"1", "height":"100px", "width":"100px"},"slow");
});
```

Comment: My example is indeed an example, and where I'm using it I can't use toggle. Tell me if I'm wrong but editing the updated jsfiddle with two different calls, I can reproduce the bug(?) : http://jsfiddle.net/Didjo/4v8Uk/14/. (Thanks!)

Comment: While my answer may not have answered the question, it does narrow things down a bit. The "bug" you are seeing only happens with the single animations, such as "show" and "slideDown". It isn't happening with the toggle methods. Figure out why, and you'll have your answer.

Comment: « I believe it happens because jQuery is seeing the element as shown already, therefore it doesn't show it » This sounds totaly sensible! Explaining why 1,1 works and 1,0 doesn't. Animate is the fix I'm use to choose but all those fade/slide/jQuery cool stuff… Well, that could ba a jQuery ticket. Thanks!